# Multi select category WordPress customizer control

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a multi select box category drop down, im having an issue with it.

Here is the custom control class:

```
class Nt_Customize_Control_Multiple_Select extends WP_Customize_Control {

/**
 * The type of customize control being rendered.
 */
public $type = 'multiple-select';

/**
 * Displays the multiple select on the customize screen.
 */
public function render_content() {

if ( empty( $this->choices ) )
    return;
?>
    <label>
        <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
        <select <?php $this->link(); ?> multiple="multiple" style="height: 100%;">
            <?php
                foreach ( $this->choices as $value => $label ) {
                    $selected = ( in_array( $value, $this->value() ) ) ? selected( 1, 1, false ) : '';
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . $selected . '>' . $label . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
<?php }}
```

Customizer option:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'nt_featured_cat', array(
    'default' => 0,
    'transport'   => 'refresh',
   'sanitize_callback' => 'nt_sanitize_cat' ));

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new Nt_Customize_Control_Multiple_Select (
        $wp_customize,
        'nt_featured_cat',
        array(
            'settings' => 'nt_featured_cat',
            'label'    => 'Featured category',
            'section'  => 'nt_blog_archive_section', // Enter the name of your own section
            'type'     => 'multiple-select', // The $type in our class
            'choices' => nt_cats()
        )
    )
);
```

and the categories function:

```
 function nt_cats() {
  $cats = array();
  $cats[0] = "All";
  foreach ( get_categories() as $categories => $category ) {
    $cats[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
  }
  return $cats;
}
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Do you get some error?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm making a loop with `WP_Query` the category prints nothing, `var_dump` returns `STRING '' (LENGTH=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified a sanitize function `nt_sanitize_cat`, have you defined this function?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'nt_featured_cat', array(
    'default' => 0,
    'transport'   => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'nt_sanitize_cat' 
));
```

I implemented your code and added this sanitize function, and I get an array of values returned:

```
/**
 * Validate the options against the existing categories
 * @param  string[] $input
 * @return string
 */
function nt_sanitize_cat( $input )
{
    $valid = nt_cats();

    foreach ($input as $value) {
        if ( !array_key_exists( $value, $valid ) ) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The most important error here that I was stuck for too long was the default value mentioned by the OP:

```
'default' => 0,
```

As we are dealing with a Select Multiple the value should always be an array. On the very first load without any value on the db I was stuck in an error coming from this line:

```
$selected = ( in_array( $value, $this->value() ) ) ? selected( 1, 1, false ) : '';
```

So with no value from the db the `$this->value()` was giving `0` as an integer and the `in_array()` was failing with a fatal error (that caught on my `debug.log`). Then I was logging the items in my log with `error_log(print_r($this->value(), true));` and found that it was giving `0` instead of any array.

## Fix

I changed the default value to an empty array instead of a plain zero (`0`) or an empty string:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'nt_featured_cat', array(
    'default'           => [], //  CHANGE IS HERE
    'transport'         => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'nt_sanitize_cat' 
));
```

And the issue was fixed.